# How to Send/Inject Packet with WinPcap

Tags: c++, c, windows, networking, pcap

I'm working on `Windows 10 64-bit` and compiling with `MinGW-w64`, also using `WinPcap`.

Trying to send/inject packets like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    pcap_t *cap = pcap_open(argv[1], 65535, 0, 1000, 0, errbuf);
    printf("interface capture: %s\n", cap == 0 ? "failed" : "success");

    unsigned char packet[100];

    // Dst MAC
    packet[0] = 0x74;
    packet[1] = 0xc6;
    packet[2] = 0x3b;
    packet[3] = 0x00;
    packet[0] = 0x06;
    packet[5] = 0xb5;

    // Src MAC
    packet[6] = 0x74;
    packet[7] = 0xc6;
    packet[8] = 0x3b;
    packet[9] = 0x00;
    packet[10] = 0x06;
    packet[11] = 0xb5;

    // others
    for (unsigned char i = 12; i < 100; i++)
    {
        packet[i] = i;
    }

    printf("inject packet: %s\n", pcap_sendpacket(cap, packet, 100) == 0 ? "success" : "failed");
    return 0;
}
```

Everything looks fine and getting success on send/inject program.

However I'm not able to capture any packet, checked with `Wireshark`, still no luck.

I'm running program as administrator with CMD, also tried to send raw UDP packet.

Am I missing something or is this the proper way to send/inject packets into network interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem! It was because of `loopback` on Windows.

Please read `Wireshark` wiki page here: [CaptureSetup/Loopback](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback)

Installed [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) which has `loopback` packet capture and injection support.

For my case, simply captured packets from `loopback` network interface (provided by `Npcap` driver) and injected packets back to this `loopback` network interface again. Now I'm able to capture the packet in `Wireshark` and UDP receiver socket reads my injected packet successfully.